# parse - notifications are not received on the first time

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse Android SDK v 1.9.2. Notifications are not received for the first time. But if I reinstall the App, then notifications are received.
My ApplicaitonClass

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
......
 Parse.initialize(this, "xxx", "xxx");
.....
}
```

I'm registering few additional attributes post login and doing saveInBackground ..... onCreate method

The activity is getting called and i'm seeing the logs before saveinbackground and no error on savecallback too.

```
.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                System.out.println("Done");
                if (e == null) {
                    System.out.println("Parse --- Succesfull Registration.....");
                } else {

                    System.out.println("Parse --- " + e);

                }
            }
        });
```

But still it doesnt work on the first time, even after closing the app and starting again. However, it works if i reinstall the app.

Kindly let me know what am i doing wrongly.

Comment: Try updating to 1.9.4, they fixed an issue with the GCM id

Comment: Hi Ashir, I have updated to 1.9.4, still it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various examples and debugging, I finally found what i was doing wrongly. I was calling remove key from the parse defaultInstallation in order to avoid the duplicates or array. 
So i need to check whether the key exists or not.

```
if(ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("secretId") != null && ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("secretId").toString().length() > 0) {
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().remove("secretId");
}
```